# Eventbrite API - custom form registration in website

Tags: api, eventbrite

We have created a event in eventbrite portal and created a campaign in an separate website to allow users registering for a event. Do we have specific API method in eventbrite to post custom form fields from website when user click on submit button and register them as an attendee?

In below documentation link, I didn't find any such API call to register user to the event as a attendee

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on Eventbrite's API/Platform team, so I can help you out here.

Eventbrite doesn't have an API method that allows for third parties to register attendees. Part of the model for making a sustainable business on lower margins relies on having an impression in front of the attendees and not allowing for 'white labeling'.

Hope that answers your question! Cheers!